# SQL - Avoiding repetitive columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

This is my code where I want to display the A.SITES_CODE and A.SITES_NAME just once where they are exactly the same. Here is my code where I tried the HAVING function but it does not meat my criteria.

```
SELECT     A.SITES_CODE, A.SITES_NAME, D.DESCRIPTION
FROM       ZZZ_SITES_AVAILABLE A, ZZZ_DIFFICULTY_RATINGS D, ZZZ_SITES_VISITED V, ZZZ_HOLIDAY_DETAILS H
WHERE      A.SITES_CODE = V.SITES_CODE
AND        V.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY = H.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY
AND        H.DIFFICULTY_RATING = D.HOLIDAY_DIFFICULTY
AND        LENGTH(D.DESCRIPTION) > 6
GROUP BY   A.SITES_CODE, A.SITES_NAME, D.DESCRIPTION
HAVING     COUNT(*) >= 1
ORDER BY   A.SITES_CODE;
```

[image: The table is showing this result:]

Comment: So in your example you'd want sites_code=101 and sites_name=yosemite to show once? What would show for the Description column in that scenario as those two values are not the same. The same is said for sites_code=107 and 105 and sites_name= zion and San Francisco. What would display in the Description column in these examples.

Comment: description will be deleted anyway, its just for a check if my LENGTH function works properly, description does not matter as long as its more than 6 characters long. Removing description from the selection does not solve the problem.

Comment: DO you only want to return the rows that have repetitive rows or return everything but for the repetitive rows just return it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `description` from the `group by`.  Along the way, you should also learn to use proper ANSI standard `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT A.SITES_CODE, A.SITES_NAME
FROM ZZZ_SITES_AVAILABLE A JOIN
     ZZZ_SITES_VISITED V
     ON A.SITES_CODE = V.SITES_CODE JOIN
     ZZZ_HOLIDAY_DETAILS H
     ON V.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY = H.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY JOIN
     ZZZ_DIFFICULTY_RATINGS D
     ON H.DIFFICULTY_RATING = D.HOLIDAY_DIFFICULTY
WHERE    LENGTH(D.DESCRIPTION) > 6
GROUP BY   A.SITES_CODE, A.SITES_NAME
HAVING     COUNT(*) >= 1
ORDER BY   A.SITES_CODE;
```

Comment: Yeah I know, I did use it a bit but I find this CONVENTIONAL way a bit easier to understand but as it seems it does not always work as I want it to work. Thank you